# Reverse HashMap keys and values in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

It's a simple question,
I have a simple HashMap of which i want to reverse the keys and values.

```
HashMap<Character, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
myHashMap.put('a', "test one");
myHashMap.put('b', "test two");
```

and I want to create a new HashMap in which i put the opposites.

```
HashMap<String, Character> reversedHashMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
e.g. Keys "test one" & "test two" and values 'a' & 'b'.
```

Comment: Simple question, simple answer. Can you tell us where you got stuck?

Comment: First of all you have to be sure that your values are unique. Otherwise, it should be `Map<String, List<Character>>`

Comment: well, I'm fairly new to JAVA and wouldn't know where to start... They all are unique, yes

Comment: This is not always possible to do without losing data.
Imagine you have this: a -> test one; b -> test two; c -> test one (in your first map).
What will you get in your second (output) map? Something like this: test one -> a (or c); test two -> b. So 1st map has 3 entries, 2nd map has just 2.

Comment: I've generally seen this referred to as "inverting" the map.  Reversing the map would be having the iterator go in reverse order (e.g. [`SequencedMap.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#reversed()).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

> They all are unique, yes

If you're sure that your values are unique you can iterate over the entries of your old map .

```
Map<String, Character> myNewHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : myHashMap.entrySet()){
    myNewHashMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a Bi-Directional map like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) provides and use the [`inverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse%28%29) method :

```
BiMap<Character, String> myBiMap = HashBiMap.create();
myBiMap.put('a', "test one");
myBiMap.put('b', "test two");

BiMap<String, Character> myBiMapInversed = myBiMap.inverse();
```

As [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) is out, you can also do it this way :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a",1);
map.put("b",2);

Map<Integer, String> mapInversed = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey))
```

Finally, I added my contribution to the [proton pack library](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack), which contains utility methods for the Stream API. With that you could do it like this:

```
Map<Character, String> mapInversed = MapStream.of(map).inverseMapping().collect();
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation of Bi-Directional map usage. I didn't know that and it is really useful for me!

Comment: When I use your java-8 method with the collectors, I get the following error on `Map.Entry::getValue` and `getKey`: `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Jan, it's because your map is of a different generic type than declared with the the mapInversed variable.

Comment: what if values are duplicate ? how do you handle that ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaUttarwar You'd have to find a merging strategy to map the different keys that are associated with the same value in your original map (you could group them into a list, sum them, take only one key depending on what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 31):

Apache commons collections library provides a utility method for inversing the map. You can use this if you are sure that the values of myHashMap are unique

```
org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils.invertMap(java.util.Map map)
```

Sample code

```
HashMap<String, Character> reversedHashMap = MapUtils.invertMap(myHashMap)
```

Answer (score 29):

If the values are not unique, the safe way to inverse the map is by using java 8's groupingBy function

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a",1);
map.put("b",2);

Map<Integer, List<String>> mapInversed = 
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simpler loop that works too (note that all my values are unique):

```
HashMap<Character, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
HashMap<String, Character> reversedHashMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();

for (char i : myHashMap.keySet()) {
    reversedHashMap.put(myHashMap.get(i), i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the list of keys and values, then add them.

```
HashMap<String, Character> reversedHashMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
for (String key : myHashMap.keySet()){
    reversedHashMap.put(myHashMap.get(key), key);
}
```

Comment: `entrySet` is better, the hash code has not to be computed on each `get`

Comment: @A4L That's true, but for simple tasks there's not much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question on how you can do it, you could get the [entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) from your map and then just put into the new map by using [getValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) as `key` and [getKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) as `value`.

But remember that keys in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) are unique, which means if you have one value with two different key in your original map, only the second key (in iteration order) will be kep as value in the new map.

Answer (score 2):

```
private <A, B> Map<B, A> invertMap(Map<A, B> map) {
    Map<B, A> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<A, B> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
    return reverseMap;
}
```

It's important to remember that `put` replaces the value when called with the same key. So if you map has two keys with the same value only one of them will exist in the inverted map.

Comment: I think a note about how duplicate values becoming keys will be handled would be useful.

Comment: @CHBuckingham agreed

Answer (score 2):

Tested with below sample snippet, tried with MapUtils, and Java8 Stream feature. It worked with both cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();
    test.put("a", "1");
    test.put("d", "1");
    test.put("b", "2");
    test.put("c", "3");
    test.put("d", "4");
    test.put("d", "41");

    System.out.println(test);

    Map<String, String> test1 = MapUtils.invertMap(test);

    System.out.println(test1);

    Map<String, String> mapInversed = 
            test.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));

    System.out.println(mapInversed);
}

Output:
{a=1, b=2, c=3, d=41}
{1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 41=d}
{1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 41=d}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use forEach introduced in Java 8

```
Map<Short, String> regularMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Short> inversedMap = new HashMap<>();

regularMap.forEach((key, value) -> inversedMap.put(value, key));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Reversing the Array of Dictionary. (If values are Unique)

```java
private void reverseArrayMap(List<Map<String, String>> list) {
    // reversing the array of dictionary
    List<Map<String, String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> resDic = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        map.forEach((key, value) -> resDic.put(value, key));
        newList.add(resDic);
    }

    System.out.println("Original Array of Dictionary" + list);
    System.out.println("Reversed Array of Dictionary" + newList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for reverting the map, in your case:

```java
private void reverseMap(Map<Character, String> map) {
    Map<String, Character> newList = new HashMap<>();
    map.forEach((key, value) -> newList.put(value, key));
    System.out.println(newList);
}
```

or you can traverse the old hashmap

```java
HashMap<String, Character> newList = new HashMap<String, Character>();
for (String key : list.keySet()){
   newList.put(list.get(key), key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java :**
Simple approach, No need for java 8

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> mapInv=new HashMap<>();

for (String key : map.keySet()) 
        mapInv.put(map.get(key), key);
```

**Java 8:** 
`forEach()` is a new method to iterate the elements. It is defined in Iterable and Stream interface.

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> mapInv=new HashMap<>();

map.forEach((key, value) -> mapInv.put(value, key));
```

**Kotlin :**

```
    val map: Map<String, String> = HashMap()
    val mapInv: MutableMap<String?, String> = HashMap()

    for (key in map.keys) mapInv[map[key]] = key
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<String, Character> inverted = myHashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

This streams over the map's entry set, and collects it back into a map with the key and value swapped.

This does assume there aren't any duplicate values in the map.  If there are duplicate values, using `groupingBy` as suggested [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375258/1108305) is a good suggestion, as each value of the inverted map will be a list of one or more elements.