# Morse Code Translator with HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I do realize that this questioned has been asked and I have searched through them for help. I am trying to write a Morse Code translator. That can Translate both letters and numbers; I have gotten the English to Morse to work perfectly using a HashMap. The Google Gods have told me I can reverse the order of the hashmap in order to get the Morse to English translation, but I am drawing a blank.

What I am looking for is a way to input a string in Morse Code including spaces and get the English translation out, including numbers?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInput();
    }

    public static void getInput() {
        char a;
        a = Input.getChar("Enter m for Morse to English or e for English to Morse.");
        if (a == 'm')
            translateMorse();
        else if (a == 'e')
            translateEnglish();
        else 
            System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");
    }

    public static void translateEnglish() {
        String englishToMorse = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in English.");
        englishToMorse = englishToMorse.toLowerCase();

        int i = 0;

        while(i <englishToMorse.length()) {
            Map<Character, String> morse = new HashMap<Character, String>();
            morse.put('a', ".-");
            morse.put('b', "-...");
            morse.put('c',  "-.-");
            morse.put('d',  "-..");
            morse.put('e',    ".");
            morse.put('f', "..-.");
            morse.put('g',  "--.");
            morse.put('h', "....");
            morse.put('i',   "..");
            morse.put('j', ".---");
            morse.put('k',   "-.");
            morse.put('l', ".-..");
            morse.put('m',   "--");
            morse.put('n',   "-.");
            morse.put('o',  "---");
            morse.put('p', ".--.");
            morse.put('q', "--.-");
            morse.put('r', ".-.");
            morse.put('s',  "...");
            morse.put('t',   "-");
            morse.put('u',  "..-");
            morse.put('v', "...-");
            morse.put('w',  ".--");
            morse.put('x', "-..-");
            morse.put('y', "-.--");
            morse.put('z', "--..");
            morse.put('1', ".----");
            morse.put('2',"..---");
            morse.put('3', "...--");
            morse.put('4', "....-");
            morse.put('5', ".....");
            morse.put('6', "-....");
            morse.put('7', "--...");
            morse.put('8', "---..");
            morse.put('9', "----.");
            morse.put('0', "-----");
            System.out.print(morse.get(englishToMorse.charAt(i)));
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void translateMorse() {  
        String morseToEnglish = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in Morse Code.");
        morseToEnglish = morseToEnglish.toLowerCase();

        int i = 0;
        while(i < morseToEnglish.length() ) {
            HashMap<Character, String> morse = new HashMap<>();
            morse.put('a', ".-");
            morse.put('b', "-...");
            morse.put('c',  "-.-");
            morse.put('d',  "-..");
            morse.put('e',    ".");
            morse.put('f', "..-.");
            morse.put('g',  "--.");
            morse.put('h', "....");
            morse.put('i',   "..");
            morse.put('j', ".---");
            morse.put('k',   "-.");
            morse.put('l', ".-..");
            morse.put('m',   "--");
            morse.put('n',   "-.");
            morse.put('o',  "---");
            morse.put('p', ".--.");
            morse.put('q', "--.-");
            morse.put('r', ".-.");
            morse.put('s',  "...");
            morse.put('t',   "-");
            morse.put('u',  "..-");
            morse.put('v', "...-");
            morse.put('w',  ".--");
            morse.put('x', "-..-");
            morse.put('y', "-.--");
            morse.put('z', "--..");
            morse.put('1', ".----");
            morse.put('2',"..---");
            morse.put('3', "...--");
            morse.put('4', "....-");
            morse.put('5', ".....");
            morse.put('6', "-....");
            morse.put('7', "--...");
            morse.put('8', "---..");
            morse.put('9', "----.");
            morse.put('0', "-----");

            Collection<String>  values= morse.values();

            for (String string: values) {
                System.out.print(string);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can use something like [Guava's BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), or switch the keys and values yourself as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412432/3558960).

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the `HashMap` by iterating over the `EntrySet`, as shown below:

```
Map<String, Character> morseToEngMap = new HashMap<>();
// engToMorseMap is your original hashmap object named morse.
// morseToEngMap is reversed map
for(Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : engToMorseMap.entrySet()){ 
    morseToEngMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
```

Alternatively, you can make use to [Guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html) which has [`inverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse%28%29) method to do the job for you.

```
BiMap<Character, String> engToMorseMap = HashBiMap.create(); 
// engToMorseMap is your original hashmap object named morse.
morse.put('a', ".-");
morse.put('b', "-...");

BiMap<String, Character> morseToEngMap = morse.inverse();
// morseToEngMap is reversed map.
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. i did try that but I kept getting null as an output.  This is the format I tried earlier to no avail, which got me frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Shishir Kumar for your quick response I saw it last night but was to tired to reply. The way you posted is one way I tried it before asking for help. I do apologize if I am breaking the rule of this forum, but this is my first time asking for help. Here is another version of the code I tried I changed variable names to match yours.

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Project {

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        getInput();


    }

    public static void getInput()
        {

        char a;
        a = Input.getChar("Enter m for Morse to English or e for English to Morse.");
        if (a == 'm')
            translateMorse();
        else if (a == 'e')
            translateEnglish();
        else 
            System.out.println("Your input is not valid.");
        }

    public static void translateEnglish()
        {



        String englishToMorse = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in English.");
        englishToMorse = englishToMorse.toLowerCase();

        int i = 0;

        while(i <englishToMorse.length() ){

            Map<Character, String> morse = new HashMap<Character, String>();

            morse.put('a', ".-");
            morse.put('b', "-...");
            morse.put('c',  "-.-");
            morse.put('d',  "-..");
            morse.put('e',    ".");
            morse.put('f', "..-.");
            morse.put('g',  "--.");
            morse.put('h', "....");
            morse.put('i',   "..");
            morse.put('j', ".---");
            morse.put('k',   "-.");
            morse.put('l', ".-..");
            morse.put('m',   "--");
            morse.put('n',   "-.");
            morse.put('o',  "---");
            morse.put('p', ".--.");
            morse.put('q', "--.-");
            morse.put('r', ".-.");
            morse.put('s',  "...");
            morse.put('t',   "-");
            morse.put('u',  "..-");
            morse.put('v', "...-");
            morse.put('w',  ".--");
            morse.put('x', "-..-");
            morse.put('y', "-.--");
            morse.put('z', "--..");
            morse.put('1', ".----");
            morse.put('2',"..---");
            morse.put('3', "...--");
            morse.put('4', "....-");
            morse.put('5', ".....");
            morse.put('6', "-....");
            morse.put('7', "--...");
            morse.put('8', "---..");
            morse.put('9', "----.");
            morse.put('0', "-----");

            System.out.print(morse.get(englishToMorse.charAt(i)));

            i++;

            }


        }

    public static void translateMorse()
        {  

        String morseToEnglish = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in Morse Code.");
        morseToEnglish = morseToEnglish.toLowerCase();

        int i = 0;

        while(i < morseToEnglish.length() ){

            HashMap<Character, String> morse = new HashMap<>();

            morse.put('a', ".-");
            morse.put('b', "-...");
            morse.put('c',  "-.-");
            morse.put('d',  "-..");
            morse.put('e',    ".");
            morse.put('f', "..-.");
            morse.put('g',  "--.");
            morse.put('h', "....");
            morse.put('i',   "..");
            morse.put('j', ".---");
            morse.put('k',   "-.");
            morse.put('l', ".-..");
            morse.put('m',   "--");
            morse.put('n',   "-.");
            morse.put('o',  "---");
            morse.put('p', ".--.");
            morse.put('q', "--.-");
            morse.put('r', ".-.");
            morse.put('s',  "...");
            morse.put('t',   "-");
            morse.put('u',  "..-");
            morse.put('v', "...-");
            morse.put('w',  ".--");
            morse.put('x', "-..-");
            morse.put('y', "-.--");
            morse.put('z', "--..");
            morse.put('1', ".----");
            morse.put('2',"..---");
            morse.put('3', "...--");
            morse.put('4', "....-");
            morse.put('5', ".....");
            morse.put('6', "-....");
            morse.put('7', "--...");
            morse.put('8', "---..");
            morse.put('9', "----.");
            morse.put('0', "-----");

          Map <String, Character> englishMap = new HashMap<>();

          int k = 0;

          for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : morse.entrySet())
          {
              k++;

              System.out.println("This is the for loop " + k);
              englishMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());

          }

          System.out.println(morse.get(morseToEnglish.charAt(i)) + "\nTHis is I = " + i);

          System.out.print(morseToEnglish);

            i++;


            }
        }



    }
```

The only output I get is null and I know or at least think I am doing something really stupid.

Comment: Do I even need two hashmaps or can it be one hashmap? I tried using two hashmaps with one being in reverse order, but it did not work either.

Comment: After doing it like this i outputted the entire map and noticed it was out of order; is this an issue?