# how to reverse the key stored in a linkedhashmap in java

Tags: java, reverse, linkedhashmap

I have a method which stores the value from array into a linkedhashmap.Map stores key as 10,20 30 now I want to reverse the order of the storage of map i.e to 30,20..so on.Is there any function which can do so??
My code is-

```
public  LinkedHashMap<Double, String> ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(String start,String end) throws SQLException {

    int row_id ;
    int bIdx = 0;

    //double[] vals = new double[47];
    double[] vals=null;
    int rowIndex = 0 ;
    int i=0;

    try
            { 
              con = getConnection();
              stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            String sql="select distinct beam_current from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where logtime between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"'"+
                      "and (beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'  or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' or beam_current like '%_0.06') ";

              System.out.println("Value of sql of FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen is"+sql);
              stmt.executeQuery(sql);
              rs = stmt.getResultSet();

             rs.last();
                int row_cnt=rs.getRow();
                System.out.println("row_count of closest " +row_cnt);
                 vals = new double[row_cnt];
                rs.beforeFirst();
       while(rs.next()) 
        {
           for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
             {
               vals[i]  = rs.getDouble(1);
               System.out.println("value of beam_current at closest is "+vals[i]);
             }
            i++;
         }
        }
     catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("\nException "+e);
        }
    //  get the max value, and its multiple of ten to get the number of buckets
    double max = java.lang.Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double v : vals) max = Math.max(max, v);
    int bucketCount =1+(int)(max/10);
    double[] bucket =new double[bucketCount];

    System.out.println("bucketcount in closese"+bucketCount);

    //  initialise the buckets array to store the closest values
   double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
 for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bucketCount; i1++){
        // store the current smallest delta in the first element
        buckets[i1][0] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
        // store the current "closest" index in the second element
        buckets[i1][1] = -1d;
        // store the current "closest" value in the third element
        buckets[i1][2] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //  iterate the rows
    for (row_id=1 ; row_id < vals.length; row_id++)
    {
        //  get the value from the row
        double v = vals[row_id];
        //  get the closest multiple of ten to v
        double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v);
        //  get the absolute distance of v from the multiple of ten
        double delta = Math.abs(mult - v);
        //  get the bucket index based on the value of `mult`
       bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d);
      // System.out.println("value of bidx for bucket index is"+bIdx);
        //    test the last known "smallest delta" for this bucket
        if (buckets[bIdx][0] > delta)
        {
         //  this is closer than the last known "smallest delta"
          buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;
          buckets[bIdx][1] = row_id;
          buckets[bIdx][2] = v;

        }
     }  
   //   print out the result
 for (int i1 =1; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)

   {
         bucket = buckets[i1];
         rowIndex = (int) bucket[1];
         double rowValue = bucket[2];
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
         System.out.println("row index closeset "+rowIndex+ "value is closest "+rowValue);
        rs.absolute(rowIndex+1);
         user_current_map.put(java.lang.Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(rs.getDouble(1))),"");

     }
System.out.println("user_current_map "+user_current_map);

return user_current_map;
}
```

This user_current_map has to be reversed.How to do so.It is defined as

```
   **LinkedHashMap<Double,String> user_current_map = new LinkedHashMap<Double,String>();**
```

Comment: You could use the key set of the map, sort it backwards and then iterate over it to use the keys in backward order.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements: do you assume/expect that your keys could be sorted; and you want to process the reverse of the sorted keys? Or do you want to ensure that you reverse the order in which the keys were added?

Comment: Just like @EddyG said....clarify whether you want the insertion order to be reversed or the natural sorting order.

Comment: Possibly similar to this one ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412354/reverse-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-java

Comment: I don't get it. You iterate the result set from last element to first, make some calculations with every value, put this calculated value in the `LinkedHashMap` and then want the keys reversed. Why don't you iterate starting from the first element of the result set? Disclaimer: it's very likely that I've got lost somewhere while reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a LinkedHashMap ordered by access order (`new LinkedHashMap(initialCapacity,loadFactor,true)`), iterating over the keys of the map and calling `get` for each key would reverse the order, since each time you would call `get(key)`, that key would be moved to the head of the entries linked list.

Therefore, this loop will reverse the order of the keys :

```
LinkedHashMap<Double,String> user_current_map = new LinkedHashMap<Double,String>(16,0.75f,true);
....
for (Double key : user_current_map.keySet()) {
    String value = map.get(key);
}
```

EDIT : actually this doesn't work. It throws ConcurrentModificationException, since you can't modify the Map while iterating over it.

Here's something that does seem to work :

```
LinkedHashMap<Double,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Double, String> (16,0.75f,true);
map.put (0.5, "a");
map.put (0.6, "b");
map.put (0.7, "c");
Set<Double> keys = new HashSet(map.keySet ());
System.out.println();
for (Double d : keys ) {
  String v = map.get (d);
  System.out.println (d+","+v);
}
keys = new HashSet(map.keySet ());
System.out.println();
for (Double d : keys) {
  String v = map.get (d);
  System.out.println (d+","+v);
}
keys = new HashSet(map.keySet ());
System.out.println();
for (Double d : keys) {
  String v = map.get (d);
  System.out.println (d+","+v);
}
```

Output :

```
0.7,c
0.6,b
0.5,a

0.5,a
0.6,b
0.7,c

0.7,c
0.6,b
0.5,a
```

Comment: I'm really glad you answered the question anyway. I didn't know a LinkedHashMap could be kept in access order.

Comment: @Eran,My eclipse hanged,while I was trying.I will answer you surely when I will try and yes LinkedHashMap  keep the order.