# Reverse Map structure using Java 8 streams

Tags: java

Given a class

```
public class MyClass {
    public int langId;
    public int sectionId;
}
```

If I have a map that maps a LangId to all the instances of MyClass that have that LangId:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> mapLangIdToListOfMyClass = new HashMap<>();
```

Using Java 8 streams, would there be a simple way to consume the previous Map and create a new Map that maps SectionId to all the instances of MyClass that has that SectionId:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> mapSectionIdToListOfMyClass = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse HashMap keys and values in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412354/reverse-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-java)

Comment: Flagging as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412354/reverse-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-java

Comment: @SobiborTreblinka The OP is not reversing keys and values, but grouping based on a different field.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, good call, unfortunately, I don't have the ability to retract the flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> mapSectionIdToListOfMyClass = mapLangIdToListOfMyClass
                               .values()
                               .stream()
                               .flatMap(List::stream)
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(j -> j.sectionId));
```