# Best way to find element in List Java

Tags: java

assume that I have some combinations with string (slot) and list of strings (codes):

```
1A - {A, B, C, D, E}
1B - {A, D, E}
1C - {B, C, D}
```

which describes the relationship between slot and codes, ex for slot 1A it contains codes A, B, C, D, E and so on...

Now I would like to reverse the order to find the relationship beween code and slots, which means which slots a code belongs to, ex:

```
A - {1A, 1B}
B - {1A, 1C}
C - {1A, 1C}
D - {1A, 1B, 1C}
E - {1A, 1B}
```

Can anyone share me an idea how can I archive it? Thank you so much

Comment: Inverse map is not a solution here because there are duplicated items in lists

Comment: Cant post an answer.Here is a solution: 
  `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("1", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"));
  map.put("2", Arrays.asList("A", "D", "E"));
  map.put("3", Arrays.asList("B", "C", "D"));
  
  System.out.println(map);
  
  Map<String, List<String>> reversed = new HashMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   String slot = entry.getKey();
   for (String code : entry.getValue()) {
    reversed.computeIfAbsent(code, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(slot);
   }
  }
  
  System.out.println(reversed);`

Comment: So just loop through your codes map and collect values to another map but with reversed relations

Comment: @alaster thank you very much alaster, i will try your solution

Comment: @alaster there is [an answer which handles this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375258/2711488) in the duplicate question.