# How to create a reverse map when original map contains collection as the value?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say my original `Map` contains the following:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> original = Maps.newHashMap();
original.put("Scott", Sets.newHashSet("Apple", "Pear", "Banana");
original.put("Jack", Sets.newHashSet("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");
```

And I want to create a reversed `Map` containing the following:

```
  "Apple":  ["Scott", "Jack"]
  "Pear":   ["Scott"]
  "Banana": ["Scott", "Jack"]
  "Orange": ["Jack"]
```

I know it can be done in old fashion (pre-Java 8), but how do I achieve the same using Java Stream API?

```
Map<String, Set<String>> reversed = original.entrySet().stream().map(x -> ????).collect(??)
```

There's similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412354/reverse-hashmap-keys-and-values-in-java), but that only works for single valued `Map`s.

Comment: Have you consider googling: **java stream reverse sort** ? Also, it smells like home work o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more imperative but simpler solution would be using `forEach` :

```
Map<String, Set<String>> original,result; // initialised
original.forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(v -> 
            result.computeIfAbsent(v, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(key)));
```

Comment: I like the readability and simplicity of this solution so I took this approach.  Thanks much!

Comment: @nanaboo Welcome and if your problem is solved don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can break the `Map` into key-value pairs (where each key and value is a single `String`) by using `flatMap`, and then collect them as you wish:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> rev =
    original.entrySet ()
            .stream ()
            .flatMap (e -> e.getValue ()
                            .stream ()
                            .map (v -> new SimpleEntry<String,String>(v,e.getKey ())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                            Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                                Collectors.toSet())));
System.out.println (rev);
```

Output:

```
{Apple=[Jack, Scott], Pear=[Scott], Orange=[Jack], Banana=[Jack, Scott]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Very good to know how this can be done with pure Streaming API.