# Using if-condition or HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was asked this question in an interview to improve the code that was provided. The provided code used lot of if statements and therefore I decided to use `HashMap` as retrieval would be faster. Unfortunately, I was not selected for the position. I am wondering if someone knows a better way than what I did to improve the code?

```
/* The following Java code is responsible for creating an HTML "SELECT" list of
   U.S. states, allowing a user to specify his or her state. This might be used,
   for instance, on a credit card transaction screen. 

   Please rewrite this code to be "better". Submit your replacement code, and 
   please also submit a few brief comments explaining why you think your code 
   is better than the sample.  (For brevity, this sample works for only 5 
   states. The real version would need to work for all 50 states. But it is 
   fine if your rewrite shows only the 5 states here.)
 */

/* Generates an HTML select list that can be used to select a specific U.S. 
   state.
 */

public class StateUtils {

  public static String createStateSelectList() {

    return
      "<select name=\"state\">\n"
    + "<option value=\"Alabama\">Alabama</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Alaska\">Alaska</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Arizona\">Arizona</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Arkansas\">Arkansas</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"California\">California</option>\n"
    // more states here
    + "</select>\n"
    ;
  }


  /* Parses the state from an HTML form submission, converting it to the 
     two-letter abbreviation. We need to store the two-letter abbreviation 
     in our database.
   */

  public static String parseSelectedState(String s) {
    if (s.equals("Alabama"))     { return "AL"; }
    if (s.equals("Alaska"))      { return "AK"; }
    if (s.equals("Arizona"))     { return "AZ"; }
    if (s.equals("Arkansas"))    { return "AR"; }
    if (s.equals("California"))  { return "CA"; }
    // more states here
  }

  /* Displays the full name of the state specified by the two-letter code. */

  public static String displayStateFullName(String abbr) {
  {
    if (abbr.equals("AL")) { return "Alabama";    }
    if (abbr.equals("AK")) { return "Alaska";     }
    if (abbr.equals("AZ")) { return "Arizona";    }
    if (abbr.equals("AR")) { return "Arkansas";   }
    if (abbr.equals("CA")) { return "California"; }
    // more states here
  }
}
```

**My solution**

```
/* Replacing the various "if" conditions with Hashmap<key, value> combination 
   will make the look-up in a constant time while using the if condition 
   look-up time will depend on the number of if conditions.
 */

import java.util.HashMap;

public class StateUtils {

  /* Generates an HTML select list that can be used to select a specific U.S. 
     state.
   */
  public static String createStateSelectList() {
    return "<select name=\"state\">\n"
    + "<option value=\"Alabama\">Alabama</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Alaska\">Alaska</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Arizona\">Arizona</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"Arkansas\">Arkansas</option>\n"
    + "<option value=\"California\">California</option>\n"
    // more states here
    + "</select>\n";
  }

  /* Parses the state from an HTML form submission, converting it to the 
     two-letter abbreviation. We need to store the two-letter abbreviation 
     in our database.
   */

  public static String parseSelectedState(String s) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Alabama", "AL");
    map.put("Alaska", "AK");
    map.put("Arizona", "AZ");
    map.put("Arkansas", "AR");
    map.put("California", "CA");

    // more states here

    String abbr = map.get(s);
    return abbr;
  }

  /* Displays the full name of the state specified by the two-letter code. */

  public static String displayStateFullName(String abbr) {
    {

      HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map2.put("AL", "Alabama");
      map2.put("AK", "Alaska");
      map2.put("AZ", "Arizona");
      map2.put("AR", "Arkansas");
      map2.put("CA", "California");

      // more state abbreviations here here

      String full_name = map2.get(abbr);
      return full_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You recreate your `Map` for each invocation so your definition of "faster" is interesting. If the states are hardcoded then correct solution would be to use an `enum`. It would be better to read this information from a database "states" table.

Comment: @TedHopp the OP is creating the `Map` anew each invocation...

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I'm not sure that an `enum` is "the correct" solution. The requirement is a two-way look-up between full name and state abbreviation. That would require at least two `enum`s.

Comment: @TedHopp the enum provides a singleton to store the data, You store the name and abbreviation in the `enum` and expose methods to do the lookup using a `Map`. Hiding all that behind an `interface` is probably a good idea too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are many things wrong with your code, not least the recreation of the `Map` for each method call.

I would start at the very beginning, with interfaces. We need two things; a `State` and a `StateResolver`. The interfaces would look like this:

```
public interface State {

    String fullName();

    String shortName();
}

public interface StateResolver {

    State fromFullName(final String fullName);

    State fromShortName(final String shortName);

    Set<? extends State> getAllStates();
}
```

This allows the implementation to be swapped out for something more sensible at a later stage, like a database. But lets stick with the hardcoded states from the example.

I would implement the `State` as an `enum` like so:

```
public enum StateData implements State {

    ALABAMA("Alabama", "AL"),
    ALASKA("Alaska", "AK"),
    ARIZONA("Arizona", "AZ"),
    ARKANSAS("Arkansas", "AR"),
    CALIFORNIA("Californiaa", "CA");

    private final String shortName;
    private final String fullName;

    private StateData(final String shortName, final String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String fullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String shortName() {
        return shortName;
    }
}
```

But, as mentioned above, this can be replaced with a bean loaded from a database. The implementation should be self-explanatory.

Next onto the resolver, lets write one against our `enum`:

```
public final class EnumStateResolver implements StateResolver {

    private final Set<? extends State> states;
    private final Map<String, State> shortNameSearch;
    private final Map<String, State> longNameSearch;

    {
        states = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(StateData.class));
        shortNameSearch = new HashMap<>();
        longNameSearch = new HashMap<>();
        for (final State state : StateData.values()) {
            shortNameSearch.put(state.shortName(), state);
            longNameSearch.put(state.fullName(), state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public State fromFullName(final String fullName) {
        final State s = longNameSearch.get(fullName);
        if (s == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid state full name " + fullName);
        }
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public State fromShortName(final String shortName) {
        final State s = shortNameSearch.get(shortName);
        if (s == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid state short name " + shortName);
        }
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<? extends State> getAllStates() {
        return states;
    }

}
```

Again this is self explanatory. Variables are at the instance level. The only dependency on the `StateData` class is in the initialiser block. This would obviously need to be rewritten for another `State` implementation but that should be not big deal. Notice this class throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the state is invalid - this would need to be handled somewhere, somehow. It is unclear where this would happen but something that needs to be considered.

Finally we implement the required methods in the class

```
public final class StateUtils {

    private static final StateResolver STATE_RESOLVER = new EnumStateResolver();
    private static final String OPTION_FORMAT = "<option value=\"%1$s\">%1$s</option>\n";

    public static String createStateSelectList() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<select name=\"state\">\n");
        for (final State s : STATE_RESOLVER.getAllStates()) {
            sb.append(String.format(OPTION_FORMAT, s.fullName()));
        }
        sb.append("</select>\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String parseSelectedState(final String s) {
        return STATE_RESOLVER.fromFullName(s).shortName();
    }

    public static String displayStateFullName(final String abbr) {
        return STATE_RESOLVER.fromShortName(abbr).fullName();
    }
}
```

Notice we only reference the implementation at the top of the utility class, this makes swapping out the implementation quick and painless. We use a `static final` reference to that the `StateResolver` is created once and only once. I have also replaced the hardcoded creation of the select with a dynamic loop based one. I have also used a formatter to build the select.

It should be noted that it is **never** a good idea to build HTML in Java and anyone that does so should have unspeakable things done to them.

Needless to say you should have thorough unit tests against each and every line of the above code.

In short your answer doesn't really come close to a proper, extensible, enterprise solution to the problem at hand. My solution might seem overkill, and you may be right. But I think it's the correct approach because abstraction is key to reusable code.

Comment: No offence, but I would *seriously* worry about hiring you :) Yet you have my upvote.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So would I ;). Hiring people who do coding for fun on Sundays is asking for trouble...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik P.S. none taken, but may I ask why?

Comment: Just a joke on your elaborate answer, but if I had an actual interviewee come up with this, I admit I *would* be a bit scared of hiring him---after all, he'll have to get along with *human* colleagues :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ha. Understood. I'm never entirely sure with programming interviews - try to get working code in the time allotted or try to build an enterprise grade solution; the two are rarely compatible. In any case probably not a discussion for this forum :p.

Comment: Truth be told, we assess our candidates more by probing their style and quality of thinking, as well as their personality; we never give full-blown, focused tasks because, as you note, it is difficult to make a sound interpretation of the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The only mistake you made was to rebuild the map every time around. If you had built the Map just once - perhaps in a constructor I suspect you would have done fine.

```
public class StateUtils {

    class State {

        final String name;
        final String abbreviation;

        public State(String name, String abbreviation) {
            this.name = name;
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }
    }
    final List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();

    {
        states.add(new State("Alabama", "AL"));
        states.add(new State("Alaska", "AK"));
        states.add(new State("Arizona", "AZ"));
        states.add(new State("Arkansas", "AR"));
        states.add(new State("California", "CA"));
    }
    final Map<String, String> nameToAbbreviation = new HashMap<String, String>();

    {
        for (State s : states) {
            nameToAbbreviation.put(s.name, s.abbreviation);
        }
    }
    final Map<String, String> abbreviationToName = new HashMap<String, String>();

    {
        for (State s : states) {
            nameToAbbreviation.put(s.abbreviation, s.name);
        }
    }

    public String getStateAbbreviation(String s) {
        return nameToAbbreviation.get(s);
    }

    public String getStateName(String abbr) {
        return abbreviationToName.get(abbr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd hardly say "only" mistake. A real solution would use a database, so when Texas secedes the program doesn't have to be recompiled ;)

Comment: @Kayaman This is interview code we're talking about. Do you suggest OP should have rewritten it to a Spring-based, declarative-transactional enterprise application?

Comment: Yes Marko. That's exactly what I suggested. The job probably went to the guy who did that.

Comment: @Kayaman It probably didn't because that takes more than 15 minutes and a full-blown development environment, including dependency management.

Comment: Yeah, unless you're the kind of super-human professional that the company is looking for. If you can't write a full blown enterprise application from scratch in 15 minutes, you're not worth hiring.

Comment: In fact, I'd ding the Spring guy for over-engineering. A `.properites` file would be more than enough for this question; that way it could be bundled into the jar, simplifying the run environment.

Comment: Heh, there are some who would say that if a company only wants people who can sling together a Spring app in 15 minutes, they're not worth joining. ;)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid manually maintaining 2 maps and keeping them in sync I would just create the second one as the first one inverted. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146990/java-invert-map) on how to do it.

Also as pointed out by others you need to create your maps only once outside of method call.

** Just for fun a way to do it in Scala **

```
val m = Map("AL" -> "Alabama", "AK" -> "Alaska")
m map { case (k, v) => (v, k) }
// gives: Map(Alabama -> AL, Alaska -> AK)
```

Comment: A simple solution there is just a method `addEntry` which does `map1.put(code,name);map2.put(name,code);`.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean

Comment: You can do somethnig very close with an appropriate three-line method `hashMap`, something I routinely use: `Map<String,String> m = hashMap("AL","Alabama", "AK","Alaska");` As for the inversion, well that's a tougher one :)

Comment: And while on the topic of other JVM langs, here's Clojure: `(def m1 {"AL" "Alabama" "AK" "Alaska"}) (def m2 (into {} (map (comp vec reverse) m1)))`

Answer (score 2):

Everyone seems focused on the parse, but the create can be improved, too. Get all of the state names, sort them alphabetically, and iterate over that collection to create each `option`. That way, the states used for parsing are always in sync with the states used for cresting. If you add a new state, you only need to add it to the "master" Enum (or whatever), and both methods will reflect the change.

Comment: +1 That "news Tate" really got me going for a while :) Answering by touchscreen, admit it :)

Comment: Took me almost a minute to type "enum" all lowercase!

Answer (score 1):

One thing I don't like about your code is that you create a hashmap each time the method is called. The map should be created just once, at class init time, and referenced from the method.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is what guys are saying - you are creating a new HashMap every time the method is invoked - a static field could rather congaing the data, and populating it only once the class is being loaded my the JVM.

I'd rather use simple switch on strings - the search is not worse than that of HashMap (at least asymptotically) but you don't use extra memory. Though you need two long switches - more code.

But than again HashMap solution the the later one would be the same for me.